# Some theorems in euclidean geometry have incomplete proofs

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have seen that, in euclidean geometry, proofs of some theorems use one instance of the 'geometric shape'(on which the theorem is based) to proof the theorem. 
Like,  the proof of 'A straight line that divides any two sides of a triangle proportionally, is parallel to the third side' use only one instance of a triangle---like:

∆ABC is the instance[image: A]

Then, constructions are added to this diagram to prove the theorem.

Clearly, the proof is not general.Because, only a triangle is in view. 
Therefore, this proof is not precise.
We have had a general proof, must be having.I haven't yet visualized what the general proof might be.
So, why do people call the above type of proof ,a proof?Is it a complete mathematical proof?

Comment: I didn't get your question fully so I just make sure that you want to say that to prove this theorem only one triangle has been used so it is not general proof because it will not satisfy on other triangle.If I am right on your question,I will say that to prove this thales theorem a triangle used which is an ordinary triangle means it is not a special type like right angle,equilateral etc.so if theorem proove on an general case then it will automatically prove on special case.

Comment: at least in my experience, the diagram provided is merely to help motivate the actual argument. the details can be written as formal deductions in whatever axiom system you're using

Comment: like for your stated example, you can see how the argument just uses the picture to help you keep track of what is what. if you were so inclined, you could just read the statements in the proof and check that each one follows formally from the previous ones http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVI/propVI2.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The diagram is meant to make it easier for you to explain and jot down facts. You cannot use "obvious properties" in the diagram to motivate your argument. For example, you cannot assume that all angles of a triangle must be acute.

It is possible for geometric proofs that are heavily based on diagrams to be wrong. A common example is that ["All triangles are isosceles"](http://www.jimloy.com/geometry/every.htm), in which the flaw lies in making an innocuous assumption about the position of a point.

Other instances include arguments about side lengths and angles. For example, if points $A< B, C$ are on a line, is it true that $|AC| = |AB|+|BC|$? In a general setting, this requires the use directed lengths.

Answer (score 4):

To prove a general statement about all triangles, it suffices to consider one triangle and give a proof for that triangle *provided* one does not use any additional assumptions about that triangle.  The reason this suffices is that, because no special assumptions were used, the same proof will apply to all other triangles equally well.

Answer (score 3):

This is and is not a problem.

The proof is in the words, not the diagram.  The diagram merely suggests which words to use, or illustrates steps in the proof that would otherwise be hard to follow.  Once a proof is written down, the diagram is logically irrelevant and not part of the proof.  In this sense the diagram cannot have any effect on the validity of the demonstration.

A proof inspired by a limited or inaccurate set of diagrams can overlook some possible cases or make invalid assumptions about the position of objects in the diagram.   This is not as big a problem as it might appear to be, because proofs that are correct for the cases depicted by some (accurately drawn) diagrams, can often be interpreted in ways that cover the general case, such as allowing negative values for length, area and angle measurements.

Comment: In the proof,the diagram and the words were clearly connected by use of constructions.The diagram has been used in the proof.Euclidean Geometry is not just 'words'.

Comment: @ReekMaths if the written words talk about $A,B,C,P,Q$ but only do so *in abstract*, without making reference to this particular diagram, then the diagram is not being used in the proof. If it says "$|CP|/|CA|=|CQ|/|CB|$, that is not using the diagram. It doesn't depend on how $P$ and $Q$ were drawn, but solely on their formal definitions.

Comment: As @Robert is telling you, the constructions used in a proof do not pertain to a diagram.  The diagram presented with a proof is there to make intelligible to a reader what the idea of the proof is, similar to comments in a computer program that have no effect on the execution.  It is often the case that diagrams were used in finding a proof, but like the scaffolding used in constructing a building, the end result stands or falls on its own regardless of what tools were temporarily used in making it.

Comment: Euclidean geometry is not "just words".  But proofs, by definition, are something transmitted in words, and using a very limited vocabulary and syntax.  Diagrams are part of Euclidean geometry but not a part of its logical structure.  The latter can be thought of as "just words" in the same way that a computer program is "just a string of characters".

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer, but here's a relevant observation about your example. The statement is actually a statement of affine geometry, since it deals only with proportions of parallel line segments, not absolute lengths or angles. In affine geometry, all triangles are equivalent, so we can consider any triangle without loss of generality.

With that information in hand, we are free to formulate a proof whose intermediate steps make restrictive assumptions about the triangle. For example, it might be convenient to assume that the altitude from $P$ to $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ intersects $\overline{AB}$. This is true if the triangle is acute, so we will assume without loss of generality that it's acute! The resulting proof will superficially appear to apply to a proper subset of triangles, but the "w.l.o.g." step extends the result to all triangles.